# How to save formatted table output as a .png?

Tags: r, r-markdown, png, xtable

````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
print(xtable(summary(lm.D9)), comment = FALSE)
```
````

In R markdown, I'm printing the latex table of the regression output for the model `lm.D9`. Is there a way to save this latex table as a .png?

Comment: Take a look at `kableExtra::as_image` https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/save_kable_and_as_image.html

Comment: Are you dead set on the `xtable` output or are you open to other options?

Comment: @IanCampbell I'm open to other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use `rmarkdown::render` to make a .pdf, then `pdftools::pdf_convert` to convert to .png.

```
tmp <- tempfile()
options(xtable.comment=FALSE)  ## removes the nasty comments
capture.output(xtable(summary(lm.D9)), file=tmp)
rmarkdown::render(tmp, output_format="pdf_document", output_file="V:/xyz.pdf")
unlink(tmp)
pdftools::pdf_convert("V:/xyz.pdf", format="png")
```

[image]